# Getting <li> and <img> elements to respect an aspect ratio on resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize, responsive-design

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEh4p/2/).

The final product is going to scroll horizontally on `mousemove`, hence the `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;` on the `ul`. The top and bottom `padding` is for the header and footer, since their heights are static.

It looks fine in the Fiddle until you vertically resize the window, at which point the images skew. The point is that whenever the window is resized, the images should take up up the maximum amount of height, displaying as many `li`s as the width will allow. How can I get the images to maintain the proper aspect ratio on a resize?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x600/000000/fff.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    padding: 128px 0 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

li img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove `width` on `<ul>` and `display` `<li>` `inline` . image will keep ration taking 100% of `height` avalaible  from `<ul>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/XEh4p/4/

edit :

1. reduced image `height:20px;` + `min-height:100%`,
2. horizontal coordonates to size `width` of `<ul>`

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body,nav,ul {
    height: 100%;
}


ul {
    padding: 128px 0 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0;
    right:0; 
}

li {
    height: 100%;

    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:auto;
}

li img {
    height: 20px;
    min-height:100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: i removed overflow:hidden, but you can keep it. you can add min-height too : http://jsfiddle.net/XEh4p/5/

Comment: Works great; I needed to set `overflow: hidden;` (among other declarations) to the `nav`, but I got it all working. Thanks!

Comment: What is it with WebKit browsers these days? This only works in Firefox. In the others the same skewing error occurs. Any idea why?

Comment: funny, i did it from chrome W7 and it worked fine & still does? just checked again both exemples in case i blew some css. ntd

Comment: Regardless of the browser, jsFiddle renders most like Firefox IME. Tested it on a local server with Chrome 27 and Safari 7 and they both do the same thing.

Comment: hello, I updated style in answer to use within a stand alone page. basicly i reduced image height ans set a min-height, and gave horizontal coordonates to ul instead of width:100%.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is with pure css not possible (as I know). You've to use some simple javascript-calculations for this. I wrote a simple solution some time ago.

https://github.com/yckart/jquery.fitpic.js

```
function fitPic(img, parent) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth || $(parent || window).width(),
        winH = window.innerHeight || $(parent || window).height(),

        // get the image dimensions
        imgW = img.width,
        imgH = img.height,

        // calculate the ratio
        ratioW = (imgW * winH) / imgH,
        ratioH = (imgH * winW) / imgW,

        // check/compare the width and height
        width = ratioW < winW ? winW : ratioW,
        height = ratioH < winH ? winH : ratioH,

        // position/center the image
        left = (width - winW) / 2,
        top = (height - winH) / 2,

        style = img.style;

    // apply new dimensions for image
    style.width = width + 'px';
    style.height = height + 'px';
    style.marginTop = -top + 'px';
    style.marginLeft = -left + 'px';
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/XEh4p/3/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work on my resize. I too tried a JS implementation, and it worked as far as the aspect ratio goes, but it produced unacceptable flickering on resize. Thoughts?

Comment: @MarcusMcLean You can try to wrap your resize handler-function in a `setTimeout` to avoid that flickering. Show me your javascript solution and I'll try to fiddle the problems out...

Answer (score 0):

for css I guess you could use:

```
  #nav > ul > li img{
   width: ... ;
   height: ... ;
   etc.
  }
```

using > makes this configuration every where the same but leave the img out or the ul or nav and it will look completely different